# s2member captcha how to make responsive - css or javascript

Tags: css, captcha, s2member

i have a s2member free registration form on my website, but my problem is this, the s2member captcha recaptcha thing is out of my box on mobile i want to make it responsive but i am not sure how to.
i looked into the `authnet-registration-form.php` and i could not find the HTML for the captcha i googled it but they did not have any thing on the subject.
i tryed doing some CSS but it does nothing like for example i did inspect elememnt on the table `#recaptcha_table` i did width of `width: 16%;` if you go up more to like the parent of the table the div with the id of #recaptch_area i get the same thing it does nothing. i also try on the img tag with the id of #recaptcha_challenge_image but all it did was make the image in it smaller.
I also notice that the recaptcha being used is out of date i don't know if that is one of the problems. someone told me that the newer versions of recaptcha is responsive i do not know if it is true or not. MY WEBSITE IS BARKITV.COM/BARKI/FREE

Please Help thank you

Comment: Not a Wordpress related question, your problem is entirely down to css, i suggest you read up / google (or any other search engine that you may use) "media query" there are loads of websites that cover this, basically you need a media query to set the minimum or maximum screen size that you will apply your css to but im unsure (as i dont use recaptcha) whether in this case it applies. Failing that contact the plugin author.

Comment: @MartinJJ it is a wordpress plugin i am having a problem with

Comment: That may be, but WP stackexchange is for supporting the Wordpress platform, problems with plugins are are outside of this scope unless the problem is caused by Wordpress itself (and it rarely is) ie: deprecated functions and no longer maintained plugins.

Comment: i know i need a media query but i need it to first fit into the box @MartinJJ

Comment: https://s2member.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the responsive view by adding this to the bottom of your CSS file.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#recaptcha_table { width:70%; }
    }
```

You can also overwrite rules by adding !important; after the style of the class.

You could even add this into your header after you have called the CSS file to make sure this is the last CSS rule.

Comment: this does not work did you even read my post dude

Comment: wrap a div inside the div to get the correct position. You don't even need to do this DUDE. Find a decent plugin!

Comment: man help or get the hell off @DanBruce